# Resend email to unresponded in SurveyMonkey

Tags: surveymonkey

I've created a survey in SurveyMonkey and every once in a while I want to resend the poll to whoever did not respond (opting out is considered a response, of course), but I haven't found an easy way to do that.

Every time I want to do it I need to go to the collector, create a new message and so on, but all I want is to resend the same message to the people that have not responded.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It's a kind of silly comment, but.. have you contacted SurveyMonkey support?

Comment: [Here is some googled information on resending surveys for partial completion.](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-resend-a-survey-to-those-who-have-partially-completed-it) May or may not help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Within the Collector, on the overview tab, you can select "Send Reminder" and then chose to send a reminder to people who have not responded at all, or those who have partially responded, but not completed your survey. 
You can also schedule this reminder, for instance 1 week after the initial invitation, and it will only send the message only to the people who have not responded at the point the reminder is sent.

Answer (score 0):

David is correct about scheduling the reminder email. Unfortunately it will capture non-response recipients as of the time you set the reminder. So if on Friday I send the survey then schedule a reminder for Monday it won't send only to the non-responders as at the time scheduled on Monday. It will send the reminder on Monday but to everyone who was a non-responder as at the time I set the reminder on the Friday. What I did was to use the api to find all collectors created within the past n days then grabbed the non-responders and dynamically created another message and then sent reminders to those people via the api as well.